# Porting Oracle programs and sub-procedures to postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

For a client asking to port Oracle packages to postgres
I have procedures of over 5K lines of code with some having like X cursors and 40 sub procedures on the inside.
something like:

```
PROCEDURE procedure_name(var_name var_type, var_name var_type OUT)
   CURSOR cursor_name
   CURSOR cursor2_name
   sub PROCEDURE sub_procedure_name(vars)
   end sub_procedure_name(vars)
   sub PROCEDURE sub_procedure_name(vars)
   end sub_precodeure_name

--BEGINNING OF MAIN PROCEDURE
end main_procedure
```

Currently I'm taking every package, subdeviding every main procedure into its subprocedures in separate files.

however i have no clue about the final structure of the project in plpgsql.

I want to know if i can nest functions and procedures inside of procedures in plpgsql.

Comment: A novel suggestion; Try it; just write a simple procedure/function with a simple nested procedure/function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. PostgreSQL has not this feature. You have to rewrite your code.